# Arquivo original padrão XML para um tooglebutton

Tags: android

Estou customizando botões na aplicação e surgiu umas dúvidas à respeito a alguns atributos.

Gostaria de ter acesso ao arquivo *default* do Android e realizar as alterações numa cópia dele, facilitaria muito isso.

Onde vejo isso?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
     <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <corners  
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"  
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"  
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"  
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" />  
     <stroke android:width="1dip" 
        android:color="#598e96" /> 
      <gradient android:angle="-90" 
        android:endColor="#7fbac6" 
        android:startColor="#27646c" /> 
       </shape> 
</item> 
<item android:state_checked="false"> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <corners  
 android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"  
 android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"  
 android:topLeftRadius="20dp"  
 android:topRightRadius="20dp" /> 
        <stroke android:width="5dip" 
             /> 
          <gradient 

        android:angle="-45"
        android:endColor="#707070" 
        android:startColor="#303030" /> 
    </shape> 
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true"> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <corners  
 android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"  
 android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"  
 android:topLeftRadius="20dp"  
 android:topRightRadius="20dp" /> 
        <stroke android:width="5dip" 
             /> 

         <gradient 

        android:angle="-45"
        android:endColor="#2020ff" 
        android:startColor="#000030" /> 

    </shape>

</item>
```

hoje fiz isso na mão, mas se eu quisesse usar um arquivo desse para deixar igualzinho o default só que com uma alteração apenas, queria o default. 
queria um que fosse igual a opção padrão.

Comment: Vou colocar mais uma vez: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/sauda%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-agradecimentos

Comment: Como assim arquivo default? Está dizendo a aparência (estilo)? Poderia colocar um exemplo de código/xml?

Comment: editei a pergunta, vê se você entende @wakim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui está:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/btn_toggle_bg.xml

**@android:drawable/btn_default_small**

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default_small.xml

**@android:drawable/btn_toggle**

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/btn_toggle.xml?av=f